# 'CORS request did not succeed' when uploading an image and Flask raises error (Firefox only)

Tags: python, firefox, flask, cors

I am trying to debug a CORS issue with my app. Specifically, it fails only in Firefox and, it seems, only with somewhat bigger files.

I am using `flask` on the backend and I am trying to upload a "faulty" image to my service. When I say faulty, I mean that the backend should reject the image with a 400 (only accept PNG, not JPG). Uploading a PNG of any size works ok. However, when I reject the JPG file, the *browser* request fails with `Network error` and I cannot capture the 400-error to display a user-friendly message. From the backend's side, everything is the same, always same headers returned, be it accepted or rejected request, `POST` or `OPTIONS`.

However, I have noticed that it only fails with somewhat bigger files. If I send a JPG of a few KBs, it works. If I send a JPG of a few MBs, it fails.

I have looked at everything

- `curl`-ing the backend gives all the right headers
- there are no `OPTIONS` requests logged by the browsers, but if there were, I've also checked those with `curl` for the right headers
- I'm only using HTTP (not HTTPS), so no problems with certificates
- I have disabled all extensions, so no possible blocking from the browser
- maybe other things that I cannot remember

What can possibly be the cause? Note that everything works as expected

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8083/api/image. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a couple of hours of trials, it appears this has nothing to do with CORS. This is probably the most confusing error message. To cite from [Firefox' documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDidNotSucceed?utm_source=devtools&utm_medium=firefox-cors-errors&utm_campaign=default) on this (emphasis mine):

> The HTTP request which makes use of CORS failed because the HTTP connection failed at either the network or protocol level. **The error is not directly related to CORS, but is a fundamental network error of some kind**. In many cases, it is caused by a browser plugin (e.g. an ad blocker or privacy protector) blocking the request.

So, this should actually indicate that the problem is on the backend, although it is very subtle.

Since in my code I am rejecting the request based on the trasmitted filename, I never read the content of the request if the name ends with `.jpg`. Instead, I reject it immediately. This is a problem with Flask's development server, which does not empty the input stream in such cases ([issue here](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1313)).

So, if you want to deal with this while keeping the development server, you should consume the input. In my case, I added a custom error handler, like so:

```
class BadRequestError(ValueError):
    """Raised when a request does not conform to the protocol"""
    pass

@app.errorhandler(BadRequestError)
def bad_request_handler(error):
    # throw away the request data to avoid closing the connection before receiving all of it
    # http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/47/
    _ = request.data
    _ = request.form
    response = jsonify(str(error))
    response.status_code = 400
    return response
```

and then, in the code, I always `raise BadRequestError('...')`, instead of just returning a 400-response.